# store a list of used cells from the array so that I can then not alter the value in those specific cells

Tags: java, arrays, cell

I am using a 2d array of integers, and the issue I am having is, that when I set the values in some of the arrays I want a method of storing which cells have been set.

So I tried using a list and adding to that, the problem I have got is that when I use this

```
usedCells.add(array1[x][y]);
```

it adds the value stored in the cell (an integer) and not the reference/cell itself.

So my question is:

How can I store a list of used cells from the array so that I can then not alter the value in those specific cells.

Comment: Your question title should not be a greeting but should summarize your actual problem. Please remove the fluff also from the question as only information relevant to the problem itself should be present.

Comment: Please update your question's title with the actual question. Also, show your code. At least, show a minimal amount of code necessary to answer your question.

Comment: ...................Title corrected and some fluff removed.

Comment: Declare your `ArrayList` to store an array, e.g. `ArrayList<int[]>`. Also, you would be better off storing the *index* of the cell, not the actual cell itself (assuming your array is unmodifiable).

Comment: Don't use an array of int but rather of a custom type, one that holds a boolean and an int, and set the boolean once you've locked the array item.

Comment: sorry as I said new here.     Thank you for the edit

Comment: @MartinBenson check my solution with class Cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use a list to store what cells have been 'used' (which makes the lookup rather clumsy), use a similar array to what stores your data.

This sample code will protect data from being overwritten:

```
public class ProtectArrayFromOverwrite {

static int[][] data = new int[5][5];
static boolean[][] containsData = new boolean[5][5];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Try to write the value 10, to the cell [1][1]
    boolean didAdd = addData(1, 1, 10);
    System.out.println(didAdd);  // True - the write worked
    // Try to write the value 20, to the cell [1][1]
    didAdd = addData(1, 1, 20);
    System.out.println(didAdd);  // False - the cell already had a value

}

public static boolean addData(int x, int y, int value) {
    if (containsData[x][y] == false) {
        data[x][y] = value;
        containsData[x][y] = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

You could also use a three dimensional array, where the third dimension is used for protection:  Set to 0 means you may write to the cell, Set to 1 means the cell is protected.  I did not want to show you a three dimensional array when you are just learning.

Comment: That's perfect for what I needed it for. Thank you

Comment: I am not supposed to use comments for salutations, but I want to wish you good luck in your studies.

Answer (score 0):

How about to store information about used cell or not in the cell itself?
For this we need to create a simple class `Cell` that represent behaviour that we needed.

```
class Cell {
    private int value;
    private boolean used;

    Cell(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    boolean isUsed() {
        return used;
    }

    void markAsUsed() {
        used == true;
    }

    private int get() {
        return value;
    }

    private int set(int newValue) {
        if (used) throw new IllegalStateException("cell is used");
        this.value = newValue;
    }
}
```

and test for it:

```
void test() {
    Cell [][] cells = {
        {new Cell(0), new Cell(1)},
        {new Cell(0), new Cell(1)},
        {new Cell(0), new Cell(1)}
    };
    Cell c = cells[1][1];
    c.isUsed(); //false
    c.set(42);  
    c.markAsUsed();

    Cell used = cells[1][1];
    used.isUsed(); // true
    used.set(0) // exception here because this cell is used;
}
```

As you can see code is much more readable and convenient to use because all is represent in one structure instead of bunches of arrays. Cell is smart enough to know is it used or not and not give you a change to change it value when it's used.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have a special class for cell presentation.

```
class MyCell<T> {
    private T value;
    private boolean isReadOnly;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

This class plays a role of a container of a value and read-only property + it may have a logic for smart update value (based on read-only property).